# With p5.js, how to use dates for line graph x-axis

Tags: p5.js

I would like to plot stock prices over time, and my x-axis data is day-month-year.
I can re-format how the date is presented in Excel, but is there an 'easy' way to use this type of data in a p5.js line graph?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend looking into [grafica](https://github.com/jagracar/grafica.js). [Here](https://editor.p5js.org/piecesofuk/sketches/rJyRDt0tz) is a nice example that uses it in a p5 sketch (not mine), I found this on Google, it was made by 'piecesofuk':

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
        // Create a new plot and set its position on the screen
        points = [];
        seed = 100 * random();

        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            points[i] = new GPoint(i, 10 * noise(0.1 * i + seed));
        }
        plot = new GPlot(this);
        plot.setPos(0, 0);
        plot.setOuterDim(width, height);

        // Add the points
        plot.setPoints(points);

        // Set the plot title and the axis labels
        plot.setTitleText("A very simple example");
        plot.getXAxis().setAxisLabelText("x axis");
        plot.getYAxis().setAxisLabelText("y axis");

        // Draw it!
        plot.defaultDraw();
}

function draw() {
//  background(220);
}
```

Results in this:
[image]